Ubuntu 24.04 не получается завершить установку
У меня есть флешка с Ubuntu 24.04. Я уже с неë устанавливал Ubuntu на компьютере. Далее мне нужна была windows, я установил windos , как одну систему разметив диск и оставив место для Ubuntu. И когда я хочу поставить Ubuntu совсемстнл с Linux вылетает ошибка.


Читайте в журнале какая ошибка

How did you fix this? Im getting the same problem

Ваш вопрос непонятен...
